# How to cancel BP in some layers in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

when I try to fine-tune a VGG network, I only want to update the weights after 5th convolution layers ,in caffe , we can cancel BP in configure file.  What should I do in tensorflow ? thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `tf.stop_gradient()` on the input of your 5th layer. Tensorflow will not backpropagate the error below. `tf.stop_gradient()` is an operation that acts as the identity function in the forward direction, but stops the gradient in the backward direction.

From documentation:

> **tf.stop_gradient**
>
> Stops gradient computation.
>
> When executed in a graph, this op outputs its input tensor as-is.
>
> When building ops to compute gradients, this op prevents the
>   contribution of its inputs to be taken into account. Normally, the
>   gradient generator adds ops to a graph to compute the derivatives of a
>   specified 'loss' by recursively finding out inputs that contributed to
>   its computation. *If you insert this op in the graph it inputs are
>   masked from the gradient generator. They are not taken into account
>   for computing gradients.*

Otherwise you can use `optimizer.minimize(loss, variables_of_fifth_layer)`. Here you are running backpropagation and updating only on the variables of your 5th layer.

For a fast selection of the variables of interest you could:

1. Define as `trainable=False` all the variables that you don't want to update, and use `variables_of_fifth_layer=tf.trainable_variables()`.
2. Divide layers by defining specific scopes and then `variables_of_fifth_layer = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES,"scope/of/fifth/layer")`